# Detect a simple circle in an image and find its radius using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an image with a simple circle in it.

How to detect the circle using numpy and find its radius ?

I tried learning but couldnt. I would like to learn from the program that you answer here.

Only thing I know as of now is:

```
from scipy import misc
f = misc.imread("/path/to/file.png")
# then dont know what to do
```

Here is the image - https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5476/14135136623_3973d3f03c_b.jpg

Comment: Checkout [this link](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html) and the example therein.

Comment: Do you know that the image will always be a simple black background with a white circle? Or could it be something else? If the image always has only black and white pixels, and only a single white circle with no other white pixels, it's much simpler.

Comment: You can say the background will be black and inside the circle will be black but circle border will be some color like red

Comment: Like there might be some random black shape inside the circle, or the circle would be made up of a single line (of some width) on a black background?

Comment: its very simple. circle is simply filled with black color.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming for now that the image always consists of exactly one non-black circle in an otherwise black image.

I'm also assuming you don't care particularly about efficiency of the algorithm.

Loop over all of the pixels in the image, keeping a sum, count, min, and max tally of all white pixel's x- and y-coordinates (min/max needed only for x or y, not both). Something like this (just roughly -- I don't have scipy installed atm):

```
circle_count = 0

circle_sum_x = 0
circle_sum_y = 0

circle_min_x = 0
circle_max_x = 0

for y in range(image_height):
    for x in range(image_width):
        if pixel(x,y) is not black:
            circle_count += 1

            circle_sum_x += x
            circle_sum_y += y

            circle_min_x = min(circle_min_x, x)
            circle_max_x = max(circle_max_y, y)

if circle_count == 0:
    print "No circle found!"
else:
    circle_center_x = circle_sum_x / circle_count
    circle_center_y = circle_sum_y / circle_count
    circle_radius = (circle_max_x - circle_min_x) / 2
```